# Handling status codes from REST API with swagger

Tags: swagger, autorest

I've developed a REST API annotated with Swagger annotations. When the API can't process the call it returns a 4xx status code with an error message in the body.
Swagger throws an exception which contains both the request and the response but the response doesn't contains its body. So the client has no access to the error message.

I know I can use annotations to prevent status codes like 4xx from generating an exception but I want to know whether there is a way to still having thrown the exception and retaining the body.

I am using AutoRest for generating client side code.